# Как разбить дату на число и время ? Qt

Tags: qt, datetime

Есть дата : `QString DataTime = 2018:11:09T12:07:04.000;` Как разбить эту строку на дату и время .....я делаю так :

```
DataTime.replace("T"," ").replace(".000","");
data = QDateTime::fromString(DataTime, "yyyy:MM:dd hh:mm:ss");
qDebug<<data.toString("hh:mm")<<data.toString("yyyy:MM:dd");
```

Но у меня компилятор возвращает пустые значения. Что я делаю не так ?

Comment: если исправить `qDebug` на `qDebug()`, то у меня ваш код дает корректный вывод

Comment: можно даже в строке ничего не менять... а использовать формат вроде `"yyyy:MM:ddThh:mm:ss.zzz"`. ЗЫ: в дате точно разделитель двоеточие, а не минус?

Comment: @Bearded Beaver да у меня рабочий код. У меня в строке не такая дата была.  2018-11-09T12:07:04.000 тире, а не двоеточие

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    const QString str = "2018:11:09T12:07:04.000";

    auto d = QDateTime::fromString(str, Qt::ISODateWithMs);

    qDebug() << d.time().toString();
    qDebug() << d.date().toString();

    return 0;
}
```

вывод:

"12:07:04"
"пт нояб. 9 2018"